# Чи правильно вживати фразеологізм "суєта суєт?

Tags: росіянізм, фразеологізми, відповідник

В [Фразеологічному словнику української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53409/361672.html) є стаття

> ***Суєта́ сує́т.*** Життєві дрібниці та їх оцінка як незначних, мізерних, не пов’язаних із справжніми цінностями життя.

Я завжди думала, що в українській мові немає слова "суєта", що це недолугий переклад з російської. 
[Словник-антисуржик](http://slovopedia.org.ua/45/53409/301000.html)

> СУЄТА  метушня

Питання в тому чи правильно вживати даний фразеологізм "суєта суєт" чи є який більш кращий відповідник українською мовою?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, згідно до [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/sujeta) такий вислів є в українській мові:

> **Суєта суєт** — те, що не має ніякого значення, цінності

І тут же подається ще один варіант:

**Марнота марнот**

[Російсько-український словник](https://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%20%281959%29.pdf) (465 ст. ПДФ) сталих виразів пропонує ще більше варіантів, і до двох наведених вище додає:

**суєта і марнота**;  **марність над марностями (а все є марність)**.

Крім того, знаходимо вислів "суєта суєт" в [Фразеологічному словнику](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53409/361672.html):

> суєта́ сує́т. Життєві дрібниці та їх оцінка як незначних, мізерних, не
>   пов’язаних із справжніми цінностями життя.

[Словник Савченко](http://univer.nuczu.edu.ua/tmp_metod/1047/%D1%E0%E2%F7%E5%ED%EA%EE%20%CB.%20%C3._%D0%EE%F1%B3%E9%F1%FC%EA%EE-%F3%EA%F0%E0%BF%ED%F1%FC%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E8%EA%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%FC.%20%D2%F0%F3%E4%ED%EE%F9%B3%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%EA%EB%E0%E4%F3.pdf) (ст. 428 ПДФ) пропонує варіант "**марнота марнот**".

До речі, вислів "марнота марнот" справді є в [Фразеологічному словнику](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82&table=uk_fraz) і в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/marnota).

І гадаю, що можна використовувати обидва фразеологізми, бо все ж знаходимо фразеологізм "суєта суєт" в багатьох словниках української мови. Хоча, можливо, в майбутньому його все ж таки замінить варіант "марнота марнот".

Answer (score 2):

Цей фразеологізм - цитата з Біблії, книги [Еклезіаст](http://cerkva.kiev.ua/biblioteka/staryi-zavit/419.html):

> 1 Слова Екклезіаста, сина Давидового, царя в Єрусалимі. 2 **Суєта суєт**, сказав Екклезіаст, **су­єта суєт**, – усе суєта! 3 Що користи людині від усіх трудів її, якими трудиться вона під сонцем? 4 Рід проходить, і рід приходить, а земля перебуває повіки.

Вираз сформований за типовою конструкцією, притаманною Старому Заповіту ([гебраїзм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F))), коли повторення слова висловлює ідею найвищого ступеня: [Цар Царів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B0%D1%80_%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2) (найвищий Цар), Книга Книг (головна Книга, власне Біблія), [Пісня Пісень](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) (найкраща Пісня), [Святеє Святих](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%94_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85) (найсвятіше місце у храмі).

Щодо майбутньої повної заміни виразом "марнота марнот" - напевно це може трапитися коли основним перекладом Біблії стане [один з перекладів](http://www.rusnauka.com/6_NITSB_2010/Philologia/59983.doc.htm) на сучасну українську мову (з семи варіантів за посиланням шість використовують слово "марнота" і лише один залишає "суєту").