# Походження виразу "суєта суєт"

Tags: етимологія

[Крилаті вислови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/33/53409/33082.html)

> ***СУЄТА СУЄТ***  Біблійний вираз, який приписується Соломону (Екклезіаст, 16 2). Значення вислову: дріб'язкові житейські турботи;
>   марнота.

Цікавить походження даного виразу? Пошук в Вікіпедії видає лише статтю фільмом ["Суєта суєт"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%94%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%94%D1%82)

Comment: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5388/69

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А чому вас не задовольняє стаття із словника? Тут же і сказано: "Біблійний вираз, який приписується Соломону (Екклезіаст, 16 2)".

Можна додати що походження не з церковно-слов'янської мови, бо у церковно-слов'янському тексті буде "[Суета́ су́ет­ст­вiй](https://azbyka.ru/biblia/?Eccl.1)":

> Суета́ су́ет­ст­вiй, рече́ екклесiа́стъ, суета́ су́ет­ст­вiй, вся́ческая суета́.

У формі "суєта суєт" вираз зустрічається у російському [синодальному перекладі](https://azbyka.ru/biblia/?Eccl.1):

> Суета сует, сказал Екклесиаст, суета сует, – всё суета!

Більшість перекладів Біблії українською перекладають цей вираз як "[марнота марнот](http://www.rusnauka.com/6_NITSB_2010/Philologia/59983.doc.htm)" чи схожих, за виключенням перекладу зробленого патріархом Філаретом на основі російського синодального перекладу у 2004 році:

> 1. Марна марнота! говорить речник; марнота над марнотами, – все марне! (П. Куліш, 1903)
> 2. Марнота марнот, каже Когелет, марнота марнот – геть усе марнота. (І. Хоменко, УГКЦ, 1957)
> 3. Наймарніша марнота, сказав Проповідник, наймарніша марнота, марнота усе! (І. Огієнко, 1962)
> 4. Марнота марнот, – сказав соборник, – марнота марнот, все марнота. (Р. Турконяк, 2003)
> 5. Суєта суєт, сказав Екклезіаст, суєта суєт, – ус`е суєта! (Патріарх Філарет, 2004)
> 6. Марнота марнот, сказав Екклезіяст, марнота марнот, все марнота. (Р. Турконяк, Українське Біблійне Товариство, 1997-2007)
> 7. Марнота марнот, сказав Екклезіяст, марнота марнот, – все марнота. (О. Гижа, 1997-2006)

Отже "суєта суєт", як вираз, прийшов з російської мови, точніше з перекладу Біблії російською мовою. Якби це був прямий переклад українською мовою - або латинського виразу "Vanitas vanitatum et omnia vanitas" або з церковно-слов'янської "Суета́ су́ет­ст­вiй, вся́ческая суета́" - важко було б отримати саме варіант "суєта суєт".

Answer (score 0):

Вислів "суєта суєт" - це латинський крилатий вислів "[Vanitas vanitatum et omnia vanitas](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanitas_vanitatum_et_omnia_vanitas)". Вперше зустрічається в [Вульгаті](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) (Латинський переклад Біблії з IV століття). Самі слова взяті з [Книги Проповідника](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0,_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), цитую Вікіпедію:

> Книга розпочинається славнозвісною фразою « ..марнота марнот — геть
>   усе марнота» (Екл. 1:2).

Comment: Мені здається дивним що "суєта суєт" в українській мові (за вашою версією) виводиться з латинського вислову, який у свою чергу взятий з перекладу Біблії латиною, в той самий час коли є переклади Біблії церковно-слов'янською і українською, причому форма "суєта суєт" швидше за все - російська (з синодального перекладу), бо церковно-слов'янською буде "Суета́ су́ет­ст­вiй". Більше схоже що стаття "Vanitas vanitatum et omnia vanitas" говорить про походження саме виразу "Vanitas vanitatum et omnia vanitas", а не про історію похождення фрази "суєта суєт".